# CSS Inline margin issue

Tags: css

Hopefully an easy one.

I am concentrating heavily on the CSS side of things in my project, but am having an issue with block vs inline elements, and I don't really want to move on as I know it's fundamental to learning CSS. So the misunderstanding...

I have a span element which is inline.

```
<span>Please Login With Your Details Below</span>
```

There is a `margin-left` of 40px on this span which shows

[image]

However if I shrink the viewport small enough it does this

[image]

Issue: So on the new line it doesn't keep the margin...

However if I change the `span` to `display:block` it does this

[image]

which is what I want.

However I read this on https://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/ regarding inline elements

> Will ignore top and bottom margin settings, but will apply left and
>   right margins, and any padding

So it may be that I have misread it totally, but from what I understand it should have applied the left margin. Can someone explain why it didn't?

Thanks

Comment: You better use `display:inline-block`

Comment: could u provide an example? I would suggest few options:
1. add height on your span
2. use line indent
3. add a div block instead of using margin-left

Comment: It applied the left margin. Span is an inline element, so the margin was applied in a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user agent decides that inline content cannot fit the containing block, it will split the inline content into multiple inline boxes in order to accommodate the wrapping required to properly display without overflowing the containing block (if possible).

So in your example, `Please Login With Your Details Below` would overflow the containing element when you shrink the viewport, and therefore gets broken into two inline boxes:

`Please Login With Your Details` and `Below`.

According to the [W3C recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting):

> When an inline box is split, margins, borders, and padding have no visual effect where the split occurs (or at any split, when there are several).

They provide this specific example that demonstrates what you are encountering:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Example of inline flow on several lines</TITLE>
    <STYLE type="text/css">
      EM {
        padding: 2px; 
        margin: 1em;
        border-width: medium;
        border-style: dashed;
        line-height: 2.4em;
      }
    </STYLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <P>Several <EM>emphasized words</EM> appear here.</P>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

[image: W3C example]

- The margin is inserted before "emphasized" and after "words".
- The padding is inserted before, above, and below "emphasized" and after, above, and below "words". A dashed border is rendered on three sides in each case.

Comment: My example appears to be from the CSS2 spec.  I'm looking for an updated example, but I believe this behavior is unchanged in CSS3.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the link

Comment: @user3428422 You're very welcome.  It seems that the CSS2 spec I referenced is still the [definition of the inline formatting context within the CSS3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#inline-formatting-context).

Answer (score 1):

Your described behaviour is totally fine and correct.
However, the information is correct that left and right margins are applied to the inline element.

The information you did not had is, that actually inline elements left margin only indent the first line.

Think of it as an element meant to be in one single line, where this line can have horizontal margin. Having the text break in multiple line is a nice feature. But from the point of view of the margin property its still one a line.

Answer (score 0):

> > You can  use this property

```
text-align: justify;
text-align-last: justify;
```